# How can I give spaces between the numbers that returned in python?

Tags: python

My code write the numbers inverted but I would like that they return like:

```html
1
2
3
```

not 321.
The language is Python, is this possible?
follow my code until now

```
number= int(input("Write a number \n"))


number= str(number)

print(number[::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you're trying to *iterate* through an *int* type, which isn't an *iterable*. You need to loop through an iterable (e.g. a *list* or a *range*) that consists of the numbers you want to print.

You want to print everything from `1` up to `number`. You can get a *range* iterable consisting of these by doing `range(1, number + 1)`. This is saying to produce an iterable that starts from `1` and ends at one number below `number + 1` (because things are indexed from `0` in Python).

So just loop through this and print each element:

```
number = int(input("Write a number: "))
for i in range(1, number + 1):
    print(str(i))
```

Answer (score -2):

How about:

```
number = input('Write a number: ')
print(*number, sep='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
Write a number: 123
1
2
3
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this,

```
number = input("Write a number \n")
for e in number:
    print(e)
```

- **e** represent each element of the **str(number)**

Comment: This won't work. You should try running your code before posting it. This will just print out the number because you're looping through a string that just consists of one character, which is the number you enter.